Can a parabola be exactly replicated using exponentials?
I came across this interesting artifact of a problem I was helping a friend solve where I used Euler's exponential forms of sine and cosine which later became of the form $e^{ix} + e^{-ix}$ on one side. After graphing that out (excluding the $i$ for use on a regular graphing calculator ie. $y = e^{x} + e^{-x}$ in Geogebra) it looks oddly like a parabola and I don't know if there is an Euler's form of a parabola that I was unaware of? Can anyone shed some light on this and show/link the work to convert one to the other?
The problem asks to solve for $t$ in
\begin{align*}
3500 &= 35t + \frac{420}{\pi} \sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}\right) 
\end{align*}
Substitute in
\begin{align*}
\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}\right) &= \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi t}{12}} - e^{-i\frac{\pi t}{12}}}{2i}
\end{align*}
Square both sides and simplify the following where the form appears on the right side.
\begin{align*}
(3500 - 35t)^2 \cdot \left(\frac{\pi i}{210}\right)^2 + 2 &= e^{i\frac{\pi t}{6}} + e^{-i\frac{\pi t}{6}}
\end{align*}
So I graphed
\begin{align*}
y &= e^{t} + e^{-t}
\end{align*}
and this happened https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/raadbwk9.
Sorry if it looks bad, I'm new to the formatting this uses.

show your attempt.

@coffeemath Ok we begin with $ 3500 = 35t + \frac{420}{\pi} \sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}\right) $ Solve for $t$.
That's transcendental, but my buddy's teacher gave it as homework and when asked directly about an algebraic or non-numeric method to answer it said, "just solve it," so I thought substituting in an Euler's Identity may work or reveal something.
So $\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}\right) = \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi t}{12}} - e^{-i\frac{\pi t}{12}}}{2i}$ into the original becomes $3500 = 35t + \frac{420}{\pi} \cdot \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi t}{12}} - e^{-i\frac{\pi t}{12}}}{2i}$

Next square both sides and this is where the artifact appeared once I graphed out only the right side in the previously mentioned fashion $((3500)^2 - (35t)^2) \cdot \left(\frac{\pi i}{210}\right)^2 = e^{i\frac{\pi t}{6}} - 2 + e^{-i\frac{\pi t}{6}}$

It's probably better to edit your question to include the with you've done, instead of just leaving it in the comments.

@JonathanZ good point

The function that you graphed is hyperbolic cosine, multiplied by a factor of $2$. Anyway, let's Taylor expand it and see the reason why it resembles a quadratic function:
$$
{e}^{x} + {e}^{- x} = 2 + {x}^{2} + \frac {{x}^{4}}{12} + \frac {{x}^{6}}{360} +\cdots
$$
So the approximation is good only when $x$ is small, and the error is quartic. In general, I doubt there is such an algebraic combination of exponentials that equals a polynomial (trivial ones excluded). Let's consider a linear combination. Suppose otherwise: Let
$$
{a}_{1} \, {e}^{{\lambda}_{1} x} + {a}_{2} {e}^{{\lambda}_{2} x} + {a}_{3} {e}^{{\lambda}_{3} x} + \cdots + {a}_{m} {e}^{{\lambda}_{m} x} = {b}_{0} + {b}_{1} x + {b}_{2} {x}^{2} + \cdots + {b}_{n} {x}^{n}.
$$
${b}_{n} \neq 0$. Take the $n$th derivatives:
$$
{a}_{1} {\lambda}_{1}^{n} {e}^{{\lambda}_{1} x} + {a}_{2} {\lambda}_{2}^{n} {e}^{{\lambda}_{2} x} + {a}_{3} {\lambda}_{3}^{n} {e}^{{\lambda}_{3} x} + \cdots + {a}_{m} {\lambda}_{m}^{n} {e}^{{\lambda}_{m} x} = {b}_{n} \, n!.
$$
For this to be true, it is necessary that the left-hand side is a constant. To this end, we need
$$
{a}_{1} {\lambda}_{1} = {a}_{2} {\lambda}_{2} = {a}_{3} {\lambda}_{3} = \cdots = {a}_{m} {\lambda}_{m} = 0.
$$
But then we will have a contradiction: ${b}_{n} = 0$.
